# Hibernate self join with second table and get all results in one set

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping, self-join

I don't know if this can be done. I've looked at a lot of forums and posts and I don't think it can be but I also haven't seen my specific use case.

I need to be able to map a table to itself, creating a link between the two records.

This is not a parent child relationship. In this case they are equal so I need to be able to access the relationship from both directions.

If UserA is Friends with UserB I want call user.getFriends() and get each users list of friends. UserA would return UserB and UserB would return UserA

This is how I was planning on setting up my tables. One for the Users and one for the Friendship

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
user_id numeric(19, 0) NOT NULL,
name varchar(128) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (user_id));

CREATE TABLE Friendship(
friend_id_1 numeric(19, 0) NOT NULL,
friend_id_2 numeric(19, 0) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (friend_id_1, friend_id_2),
CONSTRAINT `FX_FRIEND_1` FOREIGN KEY (`friend_id_1`) REFERENCES `Users` (`user_id`),  
CONSTRAINT `FX_FRIEND_2` FOREIGN KEY (`friend_id_2`) REFERENCES `Users` (`user_id`));
```

I am mapping these via a hibernate mapping file. So my question is how can I join friends to user and not care which column (friend_id_1 or friend_id_2) the user_id is in?

Answer (score 0):

In a normal Database Structure, If you only need one friend to be linked to one other friend in the table you simply create a new field in your table that will hold the ID of the person he is friends with, this is a static way and he can only be friends with one other, obviously in your case both friends records will hold the ID of the other person in this new field.  If you need multiple friends then you simply create a new table that will hold the ID of the two friends, each new record in this new table will be a new link for two friends, with this option one person can be friends with as many people in the same table as you wish.